# C# Opening Excel Spreadsheet freezes UI (Opened with Task)

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have a WPF application that opens a big excel file. The problem comes when I instantiate the excel workbook, the UI freezes, even if the instantiation takes place inside of a Task.

This is the code in the UI:

```
    excelFile = new ExcelManipulator(dlg.FileName);
    Task launchExcel = excelFile.launchExcelAsync();
    await launchExcel;
```

This is the code in the object class:

```
    private void launchExcel()
    {
        workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Path);//problem!
    }

    public Task launchExcelAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => launchExcel());
    }
```

Part of class

```
public class ExcelManipulator
{

    public string Path { get; }
    private Application excelApp { get; }
    public Workbook workbook { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Part of constructor

```
    public ExcelManipulator(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
        excelApp = new Application();
        //now in seperate function
        workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Path);//this was originally here.
    }
```

Even if I try to open the workbook inside the ExcelManipulator constructor, I get the same results.

Any suggestions or points are appreciated

Comment: You tried running it from a ´new Thread(..)´ already?

Comment: @Essigwurst

 I tried this 
    `private void launchExcel()
    {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(() => workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Path));
        newThread.Start();
        newThread.Join();
         //workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Path);
     }`

Comment: and there is the same result? try commenting out //newThread.Join();

Comment: Without the .Join() I get a crash because I need the worksheet to be initialized. So somehow I need to know when the workbook initialization inside the Thread is finished.

Comment: I did a while loop waiting for newThread.IsAlive to go false, and still I got the freezing... maybe it's because of the size of the file?

Comment: You checked if your "Excel Thread" throws an exception?

Comment: No exception is thrown. I tried to parse a very small file, and nothing is blocked. I guess the size of the file is the problem?

Comment: Maybe, but i think anyway this should not block your UI.
Do you start your "Worker Thread" from your "UI Thread"?
If yes, try to start it from the main thread, for example from "void Main()"...

Answer (score 0):

did you make it visible?

```
excelApp.Visible = true;
```

and another thing that comes to mind is

```
excelApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
```

Comment: None of this helped.